# What is wrong with this JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    u'stores': [
        {
            u'name': u'Mega',
            u'img': u'http: //www.modiin.azrieli.com/pictures/logo_mega-01.jpg'
        },
        {
            u'name': u'Shufersal',
            u'img': u'http: //msc.wcdn.co.il/archive/136894-5.jpg'
        }
    ],
    u'success': True
}
```

JSONLint.com says this:

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    u'stores': [       
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Although I can't seem to understand what is wrong. This JSON was generated with JSON.stringify in javascript.

EDIT: Thanks for the help, it was a string off python and not JSON.

Comment: what does the "u" before each string ?

Comment: It's not JSON, it's a `repr`-encoded Python `dict`

Comment: "*This JSON was generated with JSON.stringify in javascript.*" -- can you show the code that created this? Under no circumstances should JavaScript's `JSON.stringify` produce output like this. It seems more likely this was generated by Python, judging from the `u`-prefixed strings.

Answer (score 4):

JSON strings are delimited by `"` and `"` not `u'` and `'`.

Your data is expressed in Python literal syntax.

```
[ quentin ][ quentin@raston ] %  python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> foo = {
...     u'stores': [
...         {
...             u'name': u'Mega',
...             u'img': u'http: //www.modiin.azrieli.com/pictures/logo_mega-01.jpg'
...         },
...         {
...             u'name': u'Shufersal',
...             u'img': u'http: //msc.wcdn.co.il/archive/136894-5.jpg'
...         }
...     ],
...     u'success': True
... }
>>>
>>> foo
{u'stores': [{u'name': u'Mega', u'img': u'http: //www.modiin.azrieli.com/pictures/logo_mega-01.jpg'}, {u'name': u'Shufersal', u'img': u'http: //msc.wcdn.co.il/archive/136894-5.jpg'}], u'success': True}
```